# Left Join student payments

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have an issue here. I have 4 tables, namely: students, fee, payments and class

Students

> (**student_id**, firstname, lastname, cellphone, email, address,
>   photofile, **class_id**)

Class

> (**class_id**, class_description, class_date, class_venue)

Payments

> (payment_id, **student_id**, payment_date, payment_amount, **fee_id**)

Fee

> (**fee_id**, fee_description, **class_id**, fee_amount)

Basically, I need to create a query which able to show if students made the ***`payments`*** based on the ***`fees`***. However, I have tried all left joins that I got from stackoverflow, which still not able to get the result i want.

I have this:

```
SELECT 
students.student_id, fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description,
fee.class_id, fee.fee_amount, students.firstname, students.lastname,
payments.payment_id, payments.payment_date 

FROM students 
LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id 
LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.class_id = class.class_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id
```

Then I got the result like below:

```
+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
|student_id | fee_id | fee_description     | class_id  | fee_amount  | firstname | lastname | payment_id | payment_date |
+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
|     1     |   1    | Secondary Malay@Dec |     1     |     50      |  Bob      |   Smith  |     1      | 2013-12-18   |
|     1     |   1    | Secondary Malay@Dec |     1     |     50      |  Bob      |   Smith  |     11     | 2013-12-27   |
|     1     |   5    | Secondary Malay@Jan |     1     |     50      |  Bob      |   Smith  |     1      | 2013-12-18   |
|     1     |   5    | Secondary Malay@Jan |     1     |     50      |  Bob      |   Smith  |     11     | 2013-12-27   |
|     2     |   2    | Primary Eng@Dec     |     2     |     35      |  Joe      |   Doe    |     10     | 2013-12-02   |
|     11    |   1    | Secondary Malay@Dec |     1     |     50      |  Bryant   |   Quan   |     8      | 2013-12-19   |
|     11    |   5    | Secondary Malay@Jan |     1     |     50      |  Bryant   |   Quan   |     8      | 2013-12-19   |
+-----------+--------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

**The issue:**

- The student (Bob Smith) appeared 4 times (should only appear twice -
  ***Dec and Jan fee***).
- Student (Bryant Quan) only paid for ***Dec fee***, but the query shows he paid for Jan fee too.
- The payment_id should be unique, so cannot be appeared more than 1 time.

Currently, I am developing a mobile app using Flash Builder. The app is to track the payments that made by students, hence, I need to settle this issue before proceed to other. If anyone knows how, please guide me thru this. Thank you in advance ><"

The source mysql code is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4482a

Comment: Try grouping by payment_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join payments and fees table on the feeid that should give you the correct results

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
students.student_id, fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description,
fee.class_id, fee.fee_amount, students.firstname, students.lastname,
payments.payment_id, payments.payment_date 

FROM students 
LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id 
LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.class_id = class.class_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id and Payments.fee_id = fee.fee_id
```

this will give you all the students who have paid and not paid
you can filter it using where payment_id is null or is not null depending on your need 
if payment_id is null it means they have not paid and paid otherwise

Comment: i tried tis:
SELECT * 
FROM payments
LEFT JOIN fee ON payments.fee_id = fee.fee_id

but i just have (payment_id, student_id, payment_date, payment_amount, fee_id, fee_description, fee_amont and class_id).
I want to know the students.firstname and lastname. Besides, how about the students who do not pay the payments?

Answer (score 0):

Try This One.

```
SELECT a.student_id,d.fee_id, d.fee_description, b.class_id,d.fee_amount
from Students a, Class b, Payments c, Fee d 
where a.class_id=b.class_id and b.class_id=d.class_id and a.student_id=c.student_id
and c.payment_amount=d.fee_amount;
```

Comment: thanks for the help. the answer is quite closed but not wat im looking for :) TQ

Answer (score 0):

what is point of joining the **class** to **fee** rather try this.. Though I havent tested this

```
SELECT 
students.student_id, fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description,
fee.class_id, fee.fee_amount, students.firstname, students.lastname,
payments.payment_id, payments.payment_date
```

with either

```
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id
LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.fee_id = payments.fee_id 
LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id
```

Check this if wanted to have Class id to be i the Fee table

```
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id
LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id
LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.fee_id = payments.fee_id AND fee.class_id = class.class_id
```

Comment: Hi MaNKuR :) thanks for the help. the answer is quite closed but not wat im looking for :) TQ